# How is it possible to ask about who he/she said this word?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I want to ask this question:

Suppose I know that Tom said something about Lisa, but I don't know who he said it to. So now I want to ask *who Tom was talking to* when he said this thing. Which one is correct?

> - Who Tom said this word about?
> - Who did Tom say this word?
> - Whom Tom said this word?
> - or may any other correct option ...

**Edited version to more clarifications as @FumbleFingers suggested:**

Suppose we have persons A, B, and C that I know them:

Person A has told a thing to Person B (I was not there). I know the thing that person A has told but to who I don't know. Now I am going to find the person who person A told her/him a thing. So I question from the person C (= who knows the person that person A has told her/him a thing). With included the thing that was told.

Comment: Okay, I'm imagining that Tom said something about Lisa. But I'm not sure exactly what *you* now want to ask. The only thing that makes sense to me is you want to know ***Who Tom was speaking to**? (when he said something about Lisa).* Note that we don't use ***this word*** to refer to something someone said, except in unusual circumstances that I won't go into in a comment. Possibly what you're trying to say is something like ***Who did Tom say this [thing] about?*** Where pedants might tell you you should use ***whom*** rather than ***who***, but you can safely ignore what they say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I said I want (as the third person) to ask about who Tom said this thing.

Comment: Right - you want *to ask (about) who[m] Tom said this thing **to***. This gets *very* tricky, because there's confusion between whether you're using the form *to ask **about** [something you want to know about]*, as in *I'm asking about what Tom said* (asking for details ***concerning*** what he said) , or whether you're asking ***Who** Tom was talking about* (the *person he was referring to*, not the person he was *talking **to***). I'm afraid your English isn't good enough to clarify what you mean unless you use a lot more words to describe it (preferably without using the word "about" :)

Comment: ...can you please edit the question text to make it clear *exactly* what information you would be asking for (in the hypothetical situation where Tom said something, but there's some specific aspect regarding either what he said, or who he said it to) that you still don't know, and wish to find out by asking a precise question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your attention. I clarify my meaning like this (suppose we have persons A, B, and C that I know them): Person A has told a thing to Person B (I was not there). I know the thing that person A has told but to who I don't know. Now I am going to find the person who person A told her/him a thing. So I question from the person C (= who knows the person that person A has told her/him a thing) - I am sorry if my English is not well.

Comment: Thank *you* for that full clarification. I'm guessing that you haven't noticed the "Edit" button underneath your question, which allows you to ***amend*** the text that you first wrote. Although I don't have "moderator" powers, I have enough "reputation points" to make edits to *other people's* questions (most users can only edit *their own* questions), so I will do that for yours. In case you didn't realise, the reason it's important to include all relevant clarifications *in the question text itself* is because comments like ours here may be deleted later.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person A (named Tom) has said something to Person B.  However, Person B's identity is a mystery. Who is Person B? We ask Person C. These sentences should work:

- Who was Tom speaking to?
- Who was Tom speaking with?
- Who was Tom talking to?
- Who did Tom tell?   (this means he told them a certain specific fact)

Another scenario. Person A (named Tom) has said something about/regarding Person B.  However, Person B's identity is a mystery. Who is Person B? We ask Person C.

- Who was Tom talking about?
- Who was Tom referring to?

Third scenario.  The topic of conversation is a rock concert, for example.

- Who did Tom tell the story to?
- Who was Tom discussing the show with?
- Who was Tom talking to about the show?
- With whom was Tom discussing the show?

Comment: No, he is asking specifically about a case where Tom said something about Lisa (not to Lisa).

Comment: @Sam Thank you. I want to add the thing in question. Is this correct? "Who was Tom talking that thing about?"

Comment: @M.Afrashteh , added more examples.

Comment: @Sam I chose the first pattern of the third scenario: Who did Tom tell the offensive word to?

Comment: The Grammarly gives this error: Inappropriate Colloquialisms!

Comment: @M.Afrashteh Did it say that about the original sentence "Who did Tom tell the story to?" ?  That sentence is not formal writing. It is more like colloquial, spoken English.  So, that's possibly the reason for the error.   Also, in the most common usage, you do not *tell* a word to someone, you *say* the word.

Comment: @Sam: There are only two possible reasons someone might claim that *Who did Tom tell the story to?* is "not formal writing", and they're both wrong. Even the strictest pedants have largely given up telling people to use ***whom*** instead of ***who*** for the objective case. And the idea that a sentence should not end with a preposition *(**to**)* was never valid in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Agreed. Sounds very reasonable. Just trying to figure out an explanation for the Grammarly error.

Comment: I don't want to install the Grammarly browser extension myself just to see what exactly it makes of ***Who did Tom tell the offensive word to?*** It could be either of the 2 points I made above - or *feasibly* (though I very much doubt it) it's smart enough to recognise that ***tell the offensive word*** isn't idiomatic (and should probably be replaced by something more natural, such as ***say the offensive thing***).

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know who was he talking about?

.

> Who did Tom say this about?

.

> Who was he speaking of?

or the last two suggestions Same made. :)

Comment: I think this one you said is correct: "Who did Tom tell the thing about?" However, I am not sure.

Comment: @M.Afrashteh
No, definitely don't use "Who did Tom tell the thing about".